# Show that a ball in Euclidean space is convex.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $B(x,r)$ be the ball cantered at $x$ with radius $r$, in the Euclidean space,  prove that it is convex.

The notes I have give the following proof:

Take $y,y' \in B(x,r)$ and set $z=ay +(1-a)y'$ for $0 \leq a \leq 1$
So $$d(x,z) =d(x,ay +(1-a)y') \leq d(x,ay)+d(x,(1-a)y')=ad(x,y)+(1-a)d(x,y')$$

I don't understand why it's the case that $d(x,ay)=ad(x,y)$, for example, if the metric was the absolute value I can't see how $|x-ay|$ can be equal to $a|x-y|$.

Can you explain why $d(x,ay)=ad(x,y)$ holds?

Comment: You're not using the fact that the distance is derived from an inner product. This is critical for the proof.

Comment: If you write down the definition of $d(x,ay)$ you will find an answer to your question.

Comment: Ok, consider the absolute value, then $|1-\frac{3}{4} 6 |=\frac{14}{4} $ but $  \frac{3}{4} |1-6|=\frac{15}{4}$.

Comment: Its wrong, consider $a=0$.

Comment: How do you know that the author isn't claiming $d(x,ay)+d(x,(1-a)y')=ad(x,y)+(1-a)d(x,y')$ as a whole?

Comment: @JMP this might be the case.

Answer (score 5):

It's easier to see that $B(0,1)= \{x\mid \|x\| \le 1\}$ is convex in any normed space: if $y,z \in B(0,1)$, and $t \in [0,1]$, then

$$\|ty + (1-t)z\| \le \|ty\| + \|(1-t)z\| = t\|y\| + (1-t)\|z\| \le t\cdot 1 + (1-t)\cdot 1 = 1$$

so that $ty + (1-t)z \in B(0,1)$ as well. Homogeneity of the norm w.r.t positive scalars is used essentially.

All other balls in a normed space are just translations ( $x \to x+y$ ) and scalings ($x \to rx$) of $B(0,1)$ so are also convex (being linear isomorphisms).

Comment: But why doesn't this hold for the absolute value? As I have written in the comments $|1-\frac{3}{4} 6 | \neq \frac{3}{4} |1-6|$

Comment: @Randomwalk it does hold for the absolute value. The proof you quoted was wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The proof you have given only holds true if $x=0$, as then we have:

$$d(x,ay)=d(0,ay)=ad(0,y)$$

using the Euclidean metric.

It is false for all other values of $x$.